# How to delete an object after it returns? c++

Tags: c++

```
delete[] File;

printf("[%s][%d] Loaded successfully!\n", FilesList.c_str(), FileSize);

return File;

//delete[] File ?
```

Comment: You cannot. Bad design. Post the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: What? Are you returning a pointer to freed memory??

Comment: `delete []`? Something called `File` is probably not an array.

Comment: Why would you return a deleted object?

Comment: Whoever you return it to should delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you created "File" with the "new" operator, you don't want to delete it before returning it. That would leave the caller holding a pointer to a deleted object.

I think your question is really something like, how do I make sure that something that I allocate in a function and return is eventually freed?

Probably what you want is C++'s [std::unique_ptr](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c11-uniqueptr/240002708). Using this you can allocate a heap object in a function and pass both a pointer to the object *and ownership of the object* back to the caller. The unique_ptr will free the memory associated with object when the caller is done with it.